# Can we compare Big Bang theory with the beginning/ending of a Kalpa?

Tags: puranas, yuga, padma-purana, kalpa, manvantara

There is a recent statement by the Nobel Laureate Prof. Roger Penrose, who says that the Big Bang was "not the beginning" of our universe rather it was the end of the previous one. This seems to be in line with cyclical nature of Universe as explained in various puranas and siddantas.

Comment: Strictly speaking NO. you cannot compare scientific theories and infact shouldn't compare theories with statements written down in texts, purans or whatsoever you are referring to.To make things confusing there is no such theory like 'big bang' it's a public image for laymans.

Comment: @Proxy, every scientist will eventually humbly accept religious scriptural accounts of creation of universe, especially Veda/SanatanaDharma/Hinduism. You can definitely compare science and religion, because there is no fundamental difference between the two - one is a pursuit of truth because it doesn't know it yet, other is a propounder of truth because it knows it already.

Comment: This falls under "scientific speculation" and is not allowed here. BTW welcome to the site :)

Comment: @ram I agree on that, but if we leave back the ultimate goals of reaching something called 'truth'. Science can never become those things in vedas and same is true for scripture accounts. The only thing we do by comparing is to show a reason of superiority. Let science reach its conclusions, why should we recognize them of some part of scriptural account after they conclude it? At least these are my personal views.

Comment: @Proxy - Religion does not depend on science to validate its claims. You're definitely wrong about "same is true for scripture accounts". Religion can do/prove everything science does, but not the other way around, because spiritual truth (atma) is higher than material truth (bhuta) and controls it.

Comment: @ram although religion can prove everything, but then science would be useless! That's what it is, if we want to prove something in context of a science it must be done only through the path of prescribed methods developed throught the history. Today scientific working have changed drastically, if we want to make conclusions there, we must do the way they do.

Comment: @Proxy - who is denying that? Rishi Kanada formulated atomic theory 5000 years back (it's called Vaisheshika) in Brahma Sutras. Sushruta pioneered surgery. The scientific method is no different from what our rishis employed millions of years ago.